# Multiple badge count bug

Tags: bug, badges

I have noticed, that there is a bug with the number of users that earned one badge. Take a look at that screenshot[image: screenshot]

The badge has been awarded 9 times, but only by 3 users.

Comment: You're saying that the text should be "This badge has been awarded 9 times"?

Comment: yes, or find the right number of users that earned the badge